# listview reflects only filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

I want to show only the filtered data but the below coding is retrieving all the data from spreadsheet.

The listview should reflect only the data where value of column `A` is matching with `textbox1.text`. Please assist.

```
Dim item As ListItem
Dim linhafinal As Integer

ListView8.ListItems.Clear

linhafinal = k + 1

For i = 2 To linhafinal
    Set item = ListView8.ListItems.Add(, , ws1.Cells(i, 1))
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 2)
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 3)
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 4)
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 5)
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 6)
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 7)
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 8)
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 9)
    item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 10)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through the entire range and adding it to listview and hence you are getting all the data. Check if the value matches `TextBox1.Text` and then add them.

Is this what you are trying (**Untested**)?

```
Dim item As ListItem
Dim linhafinal As Integer

ListView8.ListItems.Clear

linhafinal = k + 1

For i = 2 To linhafinal
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text Then
        Set item = ListView8.ListItems.Add(, , ws1.Cells(i, 1))
        item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 2)
        item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 3)
        item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 4)
        item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 5)
        item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 6)
        item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 7)
        item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 8)
        item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 9)
        item.ListSubItems.Add Text:=ws1.Cells(i, 10)
    End If
Next
```

Alternatively after you filter the range, loop through the visible range and then add them to the listview. Currently you code is adding all of them...

Comment: Thanks Rout. Can you please assist me with coding